# Instruments > Profile - Revoke and request

Tags: ios, profiling, ios-provisioning

I'm working on an app and can launch it on the device without any problems.

However, when I try and Profile it on the device I get the following message:

```
No matching provisioning profiles found

No provisioning profiles matching the bundle identifier "<bundle id>" were found. Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.
```

If I then click "Fix Issue" I get this error message with "Your account already has a valid certificate":

[image]

What's going on? Do I need to revoke my existing certificate?

Comment: Do you do development or have access to another Macintosh?  It sounds like your public/private key was already created somewhere else.  If you are not using any other Macintoshes for doing your development, then yes you can "revoke and request".  Otherwise, I'll tell you how to transfer your keys and certificate over.

Comment: Just work on the one Mac - ok, thanks.