# Instruments > device grayed out

Tags: ios, instruments

I'm running an app on my iOS device but, in Instruments, that device is greyed out.

This also means I can't attach the process ([Cant launch iOS app with Instruments on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348403/cant-launch-ios-app-with-instruments-on-device)). Is it anything to do with my earlier question: [Instruments > Profile - Revoke and request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913537/instruments-profile-revoke-and-request)

Xcode: 6.1.1
iOS: 7.1.2

Any idea why?

Comment: Is your device is configured for development (look at it inside Xcode organizer, devices)?

Comment: Make sure you configure the device for development. Then ensure that the Xcode project settings for the deployment target match your device's OS. Also, ensure that the 'device' option matches the device you are trying to build to.

Comment: I have the same issue, the device is definitely configured because I've profiled my app before on that device. Have you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 50):

I only had to reboot my phone (not my Mac), and then the error went away
(Xcode 9.2, iPhone X running 11.2.6).

Comment: Rebooted Mac: did not help. Rebooted device: iPad shows up again in Instruments.

Comment: I rebooted my Mac and iPhone. Still did not work. `Xcode 10.2`, `iOS 12.2`

Comment: It also worked for me. I also had to close the DropBox application on the mac because it constantly wanted to access the phone to download the pictures.

Answer (score 22):

i was having this issue and resolved it by

1. Unplugging my device
2. Turning my device off
3. Rebooted my mac
4. Turned device back on and plugged into computer after logging back in.

now it shows up in instruments.  I tried unplugging device, restarting xcode, but that didn't work.  rebooting everything is what did the trick for me.

Comment: We're definitely back in windows 98 territory on the mac nowadays. Can't believe how poor the quality of developer they're employing now is!

Comment: As Max noted in this answer, rebooting the Mac shouldn't be necessary (just reboot the iPhone) :)

Comment: with XCode11.5  rebooting my device was enough

Answer (score 7):

I met the this problem. Xcode(Version 9.3.1 (9E501)), iphone 7, And I forcely quit the Instrument. It's work

Comment: Thank-you. That fixed it for me and less hassle than rebooting.

Comment: Restarting phone didn't work for me. Force quitting worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem today on xcode7.2.1, iOS 9.2.1, iPhone 6Sp. Resolved by rebooted my mac, my watch and the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If your workspace contains several projects and/or several targets, it seems that XCode doesn't know which binary to profile.

Just `Edit your scheme -> Profile -> Choose an Executable` and it should enable the profiling option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where Profile was greyed out. It turned out to be I had the device option at the top set to Generic iOS Device

[image] // this will make Profile greyed out

Once I switched it to an actual simulator device or my actual device Profile was no longer greyed out

[image]

One other option can be to in Xcode at the top go to `Help` > search `Edit Scheme` and select it > on the left side of the screen select `Profile` > change `Executable` drop down to `your_project's_name.app`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which process helped but I force quit `AppleMobileDeviceHelper` and  `DTServiceHub` in the Activity Monitor and then it started working again (I was able to select my phone without rebooting).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I confronted the question again on Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), iphone 7 and Mac 10.14.1 (18B75). I resolved it by upgrading the deployment from 8.0 to 10.1. In fact, I have meet many strange Xcode bugs caused by the version, liking this one([xcode gpu shader profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802533/xcode-gpu-shader-profiler))

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my iPhone is not trusted my computer.

How to re-trust computers, see: 
https://www.wikihow.com/Trust-a-Computer-on-an-iPhone

In short, you should reset Location and Privacy in settings, and then plug-in your iPhone again. And you will see 'Trust this computer' again.

Answer (score 0):

My issue what that it was asking me to trust the computer every time I plugged it in.

To fix it, I had to turn on the Hotspot then turn it back off.