# Xcode GPU shader profiler

Tags: profiler, metal, xcode10

The Xcode->GPU Capture frame->GPU shader profiler can't work, I run the Capture frame, and open the Metal compute shader source code by GPU shader profiler. But I can't see the shader code performance profile like that[GPU shader profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGO3F.png)

Comment: Is your project a Mac app or an iOS app? If it's an iOS app, are you profiling on the device or the simulator? I think you can only get shader per-line profiling on iOS devices.

Comment: Thx, I'm sure it's iOS app, and profiling on My iPhone 7 .I doubted whether some scheme manage setting is wrong. But I check the setting. building configuration is debug,  GPU capture frame is Metal, and Metal API Validation is Enable. I also wondered The shader pipeline time is short, but longer pipeline time doesn't work

Comment: What version of iOS and XCode are you using?

Comment: xcode Version 9.3.1 (9E501), iOS 11.3. In fact I has doubt My xcode for  a long  while, but I don't know xcode has the different version. Do you mean liking Visual Studio's different version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your project's "iOS Deployment Target" to a higher version. I had this issue and in my case it was set to 9.x. When I set it to 11.4 I could see the percentage on source lines.