# Xcode Instruments shows Device is offline

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments

I have been trying to run the app to check the performance using `Core Animation` profiler in Xcode Instruments. Even though the device is online it shows up `Device is offline`.

I tried getting the work done as per the various suggestions provided here [instruments-device-grayed-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913801/instruments-device-grayed-out). But nothing worked work apparently.

Could anybody suggest how do i get this working.

Specification:
**Xcode - 10.2
iOS - 12.2**

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I got mine working with these steps  **1.** Quit Xcode **2.** Unplug the iPhone/iPad **3.** Start the Xcode and plug the device **4.** Try running the core animation. If it still the same **5.** Open a different project and run the core animation **6.** Then come back and try with your Project

Answer (score 28):

The following worked for me (some steps may be unnecessary):

1. Quit Xcode
2. Unplug iPhone
3. Restart iPhone
4. Start Xcode
5. Plug in iPhone
6. Profile

Comment: I´ve had the issue with XCode 11.1 und .2. Restarting the phone was the part making the difference for me and eventually resolving it.

Comment: Unplugging and plugging the phone was the main solution for me

Comment: ths！help for me

Comment: Cool it's works!

Comment: In my case, restart the device / Xcode doesn't help at all. I have to restart the macOS to make it work.

Comment: For me, only restarting 'Instruments' work

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out that my iPhone is not trusted my computer.

See my answer in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60732605/3051096

Answer (score -1):

If you Not reslove the problem as `Jaysen Marais` said Reset and Restart Xcode.
You can try this way:

Open Instrument by Left Navigator - `Memory` - `Profile in Instruments` and a alert as blew, you should select `Restart`, and then waiting reopen the Instrument.

Then all is OK for me.

[image]